# How can I delete lines that have some special character with command line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, command

Hi I have a long file like this:

```
information_1 this is my file....@s...asdadada 
information_2 this is my file....s...asdadada sdsfsd
information_3 this is my file@sasdadada 
information_4 this is my filesasdadada 
information_5 this is my filesasdadada@
```

And I want a file like this, whitout the lines that contains "@" charachter:

```
information_2 this is my file....s...asdadada sdsfsd
information_4 this is my filesasdadada
```

How can I do it with bash commands like sed, awk...?

Answer (score 4):

With sed :

```
 sed '/@/d' file
```

Deletes all lines that contain a `@`.

With grep :

```
grep -v @ file
```

Output lines that does not contain a `@`.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
$ awk '!/@/' file
information_2 this is my file....s...asdadada sdsfsd
information_4 this is my filesasdadada
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless /@/' file
```

To replace in file (also create a backup .BAK for example, more precisely rename file to file.BAK and create new file with the same name)

```
$ perl -i.BAK -ne 'print unless /@/' file
```